# Cannot calculate roc_auc_score, only one class present in y_true

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I want to print sklearn `roc_auc_score` and I have this error :

```
ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.
```

I use random forest to predict topics in text.

my code :

```
# No validation data in rnd forest
x_train = np.concatenate((x_train, x_valid))
y_train = np.concatenate((y_train, y_valid))

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=int(clf_params['n_estimators']),
                                   max_features=clf_params['max_features'])
model.fit(pipe_vect.transform(x_train), y_train)

x_test_vect = pipe_vect.transform(x_test)
y_pred = model.predict_proba(x_test_vect) 
auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: It looks like `y_test` only contains a single class, making ROC AUC score undefined?

Comment: @dspencer yes it's the case, how can i change the number of class ? if you can help me i will be very grateful :)

Comment: How is `y_test`being defined? The classes will depend on your data set.

Comment: Please include how exactly you have split your data to `x_train` and `x_test`.

Comment: @dspencer y_test is a list of words, the problem is that y_test an y_pred havn't the same dimension, how can i give them the same dimension ? thanks

Comment: @desertnaut  y_test is a list of words, the problem is that y_test an y_pred havn't the same dimension, how can i give them the same dimension ? thanks

Comment: How's the labelling for the y_test? If there is label encoding and if all the list of words are given the same label encoding value this problem will also occur